# Comparing two variables at different times

Tags: android

I'm new to Android application development, would like to compare different variables over time.
My Service counts the number of SMS inside the smart-phone.

```
private static final Uri SMS_URI_ALL = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
final List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    String id;

    final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SmsReader.SMS_URI_ALL,null, null,null, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            messages.add(id);
            currentMessage = messages.size();
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    if (! cursor.isClosed()){
        cursor.close();
}
```

Every 15 mins service will be starts, and I would like to compare the value of "currentMessage" and calculate the difference between the old value of "currentMessage" and the new value of "currentMessage" for know how many message I have sent, received during this period of 15min
I don't know how to implement it, can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the count in database, also you cannot exactly monitor the count this way. Add broadcast receiver for when a sms is sent or received.

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution, I save the value inside a file, and I compare the current value whith the older value